# Converting Integer to String with comma for thousands

Tags: java, string, integer

I want to convert an Integer 35634646 to have the thousand "," so it should be 35,634,646.

What would be the quickest way to doing that?

Answer (score 327, accepted):

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(35634646));
```

```
Output: 35,634,646
```

Comment: I had to add `import java.text.NumberFormat;`.

Comment: This forces the US style grouping which always uses `,`, however there are also regions using `.` for grouping instead. In a word, hard-coding a locale is considered a bad practice.

Comment: @DreaminginCode To do it well `Locale.getCurrent()` is the solution

Comment: @RogerRV There is no Locale.getCurrent() (at least on android)

Comment: Yeh this is not the best answer for the 96% of people who don't live in the USA

Comment: @MikeS I had to add Japan local in getNumberInstance(Locale.JP)... Is This correct? It is not working for me

Answer (score 166):

You ask for quickest, but perhaps you mean "best" or "correct" or "typical"?

You also ask for commas to indicate thousands, but perhaps you mean "in normal human readable form according to the local custom of your user"?

You do it as so:

```
    int i = 35634646;
    String s = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(i);
```

Americans will get "35,634,646"

Germans will get "35.634.646"

Swiss Germans will get "35'634'646"

Comment: Where can I get the number pattern of each locale? I tried to read the code but can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 98):

```
int bigNumber = 1234567;
String formattedNumber = String.format("%,d", bigNumber);
```

Comment: Note: This implements the locale-specific grouping.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dnum

Comment: I prefer this less verbose method than using NumberFormat

Answer (score 57):

**Integers:**

```
int value = 100000; 
String.format("%,d", value); // outputs 100,000
```

**Doubles:**

```
double value = 21403.3144d;
String.format("%,.2f", value); // outputs 21,403.31
```

---

[String.format is pretty powerful.](https://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm)

-
Edited per [psuzzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029912/psuzzi) feedback.

Comment: Advantage: No "new", does not load up the garbage collector (unlike DecimalFormat).

Comment: Have a look in `String.format`. It starts with `return new Formatter(l) ...` etc. So the garbage collector argument is not as strong at it seems.

Comment: This is my favorite answer, the question asks to work with Integer, so here is the code: 
    int value = 100000;
    String.format("%,d", value);

Comment: I like this one.

Answer (score 21):

```
 int value = 35634646;
 DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
 String output = myFormatter.format(value);
 System.out.println(output);
```

Output: `35,634,646`

Comment: Your pattern need not be more than `#,###`, if you want european style formatting then you can use `#,##,###`.

Comment: @Ali: The format you describe is only used in India, and I'm at least 90% sure India isn't in Europe.

Comment: I get it... fine, if you need indian formatting then that's how you do it.

Comment: This is locale dependent and will not produce the correct (as per question) output if run where the default locale doesn't separate thousands with a `,`.

Answer (score 19):

The other answers are correct, however double-check your locale before using `"%,d"`:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
int bigNumber = 35634646;
String formattedNumber = String.format("%,d", bigNumber);
System.out.println(formattedNumber);

Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pl", "PL"));
formattedNumber = String.format("%,d", bigNumber);
System.out.println(formattedNumber);
```

Result:

```
35,634,646
35 634 646
```

Answer (score 6):

use Extension

```
import java.text.NumberFormat

val Int.commaString: String
  get() = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(this)

val String.commaString: String
  get() = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(this.toDouble())

val Long.commaString: String
  get() = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(this)

val Double.commaString: String
  get() = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(this)
```

result

```
1234.commaString => 1,234
"1234.456".commaString => 1,234.456
1234567890123456789.commaString => 1,234,567,890,123,456,789
1234.456.commaString => 1,234.456
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked for me:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(Integer.valueOf("String Your Number"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `%d` format specifier with a comma: `%,d`

This is by far the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

here's a solution for those of you who can't access "numberformat" nor "String.format" (using a limited version of java inside a framework). Hope it's useful.

```
number= 123456789;
thousandsSeparator=",";
myNumberString=number.toString();   
numberLength=myNumberString.length;
howManySeparators=Math.floor((numberLength-1)/3)
formattedString=myNumberString.substring(0,numberLength-(howManySeparators*3))
while (howManySeparators>0)    {
formattedString=formattedString+thousandsSeparator+myNumberString.substring(numberLength-(howManySeparators*3),numberLength-((howManySeparators-1)*3));
howManySeparators=howManySeparators-1;    }

formattedString
```

Comment: Consider to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55066145/edit) your answer adding some comments to your code (and maybe wrap it in a method, so it can be more useful)

Answer (score 0):

If the same has to be done in the JSP , use:

```
<fmt:formatNumber pattern="#,##0" value="${yourlist.yourintvalue}" var="formattedVariable" />
<c:out value="${formattedVariable}"></c:out>
```

ofcourse for multiple values use :

```
<c:forEach items="${yourlist}" var="yourlist">

    <fmt:formatNumber pattern="#,##0" value="${yourlist.yourintvalue}" var="formattedVariable" />
    <c:out value="${formattedVariable}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way that also able you to replace default separator with any characters:

```
val myNumber = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US)
   .format(123456789)
   .replace(",", "،")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
@inpute 100000
@return 1,000,000
*/
    public static String addComma(long amount) {
        return NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(amount);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

can't you use a

```
System.out.printf("%n%,d",int name);
```

The comma in the `printf` should add the commas into the `%d` inter.

Not positive about it, but works for me.

Comment: that's not compiling for me

Comment: "Not positive about it."  Pointless.

Answer (score -8):

First you need to include the JSTL tags :-

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

at the start of the page