# Convert string to int for summation, then back to string with commas where necessary

Tags: java, string, int

I have some numbers that are represented as Strings. Some of them are formatted like this, "12,309". I need to change them to ints, sum them, and then change them back to strings with commas in the appropriate place. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Take a look at these two SO questions:

[String to integer][1]

[Integer to string][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097332/convert-a-string-to-number-java
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070209/converting-integer-to-string-with-comma-for-thousands

Comment: I've tried Integer.valueOf() but that doesn't work because it doesn't get rid of the comma. I've also tried to use NumberFormat but I'm not really sure how that works.

Comment: @TGMCians, good point (about my deleted answer), others have covered this to a much better depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class to specify a format with commas.  Use the `parse` method to parse a `String` into a `Number`, and the `format` method to convert it back into a `String` with commas.

A format string "#,###" should be sufficient to represent comma-separated numbers such as 1,234,567.

Comment: This is the right tool for the job. OP should take a look at [the Numbers and Currencies tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberintro.html).

Comment: This is a much neater solution than the one I gave using regex, thanks rgettman!

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions for a space delimited string this would work

```
String regex = "(?<=[\\d])(,)(?=[\\d])";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

String str = "12,000 1,000 42";

int currentInt = 0;
int sum = 0; 
String currentStr = "";

for(int i = 0; i < commaDelimitedNumbers.length; i++){

    currentStr = commaDelimitedNumbers[i];

    Matcher m = p.matcher(currentStr);

    currentStr = m.replaceAll("");

    currentInt = Integer.parseInt(currentStr);

    sum  += currentInt;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Why the use of patter/matcher ?

Comment: @giorashc In case he has other characters in between the numbers in the file. This is the most general solution to the problem.

Comment: and what if it does not match ? your solution does not cover that

Comment: @giorashc I tested it and it worked fine even with no match. Which input string does it not work with?

Comment: oh my I read your pattern wrong. my mistake.