# String.format returning a double that uses comma as separator

Tags: java, string

I'm making a random file generator that makes a txt with random cartesian points
the problem is: when I use the String.format to a number (let's say 4.3), I get "4,3". But I don't want the comma, I don't even know why it makes a comma, there's no use to it at all...
The code:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("txt.txt"));
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
Random generator = new Random();
int nPoints = generator.nextInt(10)+10;
bufferedWriter.write(""+nPoints);
for (int n=0; n<nPoints; n++){
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    String x = String.format("%.1f", generator.nextDouble()*100-50);
    String y = String.format("%.1f", generator.nextDouble()*100-50);
    bufferedWriter.write(x + " " + y);
}
bufferedWriter.close();
```

I've solved the problem using replace(",", "."), but I kinda think this is not a good solution, and I want to know if there's any reason to have a comma in the format method.

Comment: What local are you using?

Comment: What does  `Locale.getDefault()` return on your system?

Comment: @MadProgrammer `The Anglesey Arms` - why is that important?

Comment: I hate those nonstandardized functions... Thanks everyone, I think I'll keep the .replace to solve the problem.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Absolutely! How else do I know where you'll be buying me that beer ;)

Comment: You could use `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale)` to change the way a value is formatted...

Comment: Checkout this...Local dependency http://stackoverflow.com/a/7070368/2624806

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a workaround (replace the comma by a dot) you should solve it in a proper way. "There is an API for that."

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
String portuguese = String.format("%.1f", 1.4d);
String english = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.1f", 1.4d);
System.out.println("pt_BR = " + portuguese);
System.out.println("en_GB = " + english);
```

produced output

```
pt_BR = 1,4
en_GB = 1.4
```

And it's not a `nonstandardized function` [(see the Javadoc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)). Standard is `use the default locale` and if needed `you are able to change the behavior`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
        DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
        otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("####.0",otherSymbols);

        for (int n=0; n<nPoints; n++){
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            String x = formatter.format(generator.nextDouble()*100-50);
            String y = formatter.format(generator.nextDouble()*100-50);
```

The output :

```
33.1 -37.7
```