# Add commas or point every 3 digits using kotlin

Tags: kotlin, numbers, number-formatting

I want to add commas or point every 3 digit in EditText input.

Example :

- input : 1000. Output : 1.000
- input : 11000. Output : 11.000

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you are on the JVM you can use

```
"%,d".format(input)
```

which gives `11,000` for input `11000`. Replace `,` with any delimiter you require.

If you want to use predefined number formats, e.g. for the current locale, use:

```
java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(input);
```

Be also sure to check the other format instances, e.g. `getCurrencyInstance` or `getPercentInstance`. Note that you can use `NumberFormat` also with other locales. Just pass them to the `get*Instance`-method.

Some of the second variant can also be found here: [Converting Integer to String with comma for thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070209/converting-integer-to-string-with-comma-for-thousands)

If you are using it via Javascript you may be interested in: [How do I format numbers using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-do-i-format-numbers-using-javascript)

Comment: Works if delimiter is a comma, but for apostrophe' I get an UnknownFormatConversionException.

Comment: Please check [the Formatter Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) to see which flags are supported or how the formatting string can be constructed in detail. The ',' is just one of the possible flags (locale-specific grouping separator) . The chapter [Number Localization Algorithm](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#L10nAlgorithm) contains specific details about number formatting.

Answer (score 16):

Based on Splitframe answer above, did a simplified version (without the `var`):

```
fun Int.formatDecimalSeparator(): String {
    return toString()
        .reversed()
        .chunked(3)
        .joinToString(",")
        .reversed()
}
```

And added some tests:

```
    @Test
    fun whenFormatDecimal_thenReturnFormatted() {
        mapOf(
            1 to "1",
            12 to "12",
            123 to "123",
            1234 to "1,234",
            12345 to "12,345",
            123456 to "123,456",
            1234567 to "1,234,567",
            12345678 to "12,345,678",
            123456789 to "123,456,789",
            1234567890 to "1,234,567,890",
        ).forEach { (test, expected) ->
            val result = test.formatDecimalSeparator()
            assertEquals(expected, result)
        }
    }
```

In my case is a KMM project, and we don't support other languages, so it does the job. A better solution I would say to create an `expect` Util class and each platform implement the formatter taking account of the user Locale, etc.

Comment: Oh cool! It didn't occur to me to use chunked on the String. Nice solution. Should be added to default Kotlin for `Number`.

Comment: thanks been searching for this as well for KMM solutions!

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple way that able you to replace default separator with any characters:

```
val myNumber = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US)
   .format(123456789)
   .replace(",", "،")
```

Answer (score 3):

System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(35634646));

Answer (score 3):

This might help

```kotlin
fun format(amount):String{
    val numberFormat = DecimalFormat("#,###.00")
    return numberFormat.format(amount)
}
```

Comment: How come no one vote for this simple and usefule answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used this for a non JVM Kotlin environment:

```
fun formatDecimalSeperators(number :String) :String {
    var index = 1
    return number
            .takeIf { it.length > 3 }
            ?.reversed()
            ?.map { if (index++ % 3 == 0) "$it," else it }
            ?.joinToString("")
            ?.reversed()
            ?.removePrefix(",")
            ?: number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use @Roland answer in Android String Resources to format it:

```
<string name="answer_count">%,01d answers</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a an extension function taking care of your case but also

- Decimal position
- Language consideration
- Flooring

  ```
  fun Number.toFormattedNumber(significantDecimalPlaces: Int = 2): String? 
  {

     val df = DecimalFormat(
      "#,###."+"#".repeat(significantDecimalPlaces),
      DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH)
     )
     df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.FLOOR
     return try {
       df.format(this.toDouble())
     }catch (e: Exception){
       null
     }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

this is other solution

```
fun separateDigit(text: String): String {
var reversedText = text.reversed()
var formattedText = ""
while (reversedText.length > 3) {
    formattedText += "${reversedText.take(3)},"
    reversedText = reversedText.drop(3)
    }
formattedText += reversedText
return "${formattedText.reversed()}"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For a method without getting Locale, you can use an extension to convert your Int into a formatted String like this below :

```
fun Int.formatWithThousandComma(): String {
    val result = StringBuilder()
    val size = this.toString().length
    return if (size > 3) {
        for (i in size - 1 downTo 0) {
            result.insert(0, this.toString()[i])
            if ((i != size - 1) && i != 0 && (size - i) % 3 == 0)
                result.insert(0, "\'")
        }
        result.toString()
    } else
        this.toString()
}
```