# How to add Commas in large numbers fetched using Json in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new in andoid studio and trying out Json, fetching Covid-19 data from an API. Please i want to add commas to large numbers fetched using Json. Here's the code below. I tried everything but no avail. I dont know if  TextView need to be changed to another data format to allow that. The numbers just dispaly without commas.  Thanks as you help me out.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;



import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Create the object of TextView
    TextView tvCases, tvRecovered,
            tvCritical, tvActive,
            tvTodayCases, tvTotalDeaths,
            tvTodayDeaths,
            tvAffectedCountries;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Link those objects with their respective id's
        // that we have given in .XML file
        tvCases
                = findViewById(R.id.tvCases);

        tvRecovered
                = findViewById(R.id.tvRecovered);
        tvCritical
                = findViewById(R.id.tvCritical);
        tvActive
                = findViewById(R.id.tvActive);
        tvTodayCases
                = findViewById(R.id.tvTodayCases);
        tvTotalDeaths
                = findViewById(R.id.tvTotalDeaths);
        tvTodayDeaths
                = findViewById(R.id.tvTodayDeaths);
        

        // Creating a method fetchdata()
        fetchdata();
    }

    private void fetchdata()
    {

        // Create a String request
        // using Volley Library
        String url = "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/Nigeria";

        StringRequest request
                = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {

                        // Handle the JSON object and
                        // handle it inside try and catch
                        try {

                            // Creating object of JSONObject
                            JSONObject jsonObject
                                    = new JSONObject(
                                    response.toString());

                            // Set the data in text view
                            // which are available in JSON format
                            // Note that the parameter inside
                            // the getString() must match
                            // with the name given in JSON format
                            tvCases.setText(
                                    jsonObject.getString(
                                            "cases"));

                            tvRecovered.setText(
                                    jsonObject.getString(
                                            "recovered"));
                            tvCritical.setText(
                                    jsonObject.getString(
                                            "critical"));
                            tvActive.setText(
                                    jsonObject.getString(
                                            "active"));
                            tvTodayCases.setText(
                                    jsonObject.getString(
                                            "todayCases"));
                            tvTotalDeaths.setText(
                                    jsonObject.getString(
                                            "deaths"));
                            tvTodayDeaths.setText(
                                    jsonObject.getString(
                                            "todayDeaths"));

                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                error.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue
                = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070209/converting-integer-to-string-with-comma-for-thousands

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

first get the JSON data then convert it to long and use Number format.

This for total cases :

`String total_json = jsonObject.getString("cases");`
`long totals = Long.parseLong(total_json);`
`total.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(totals));`